Modelling with drag & drop softwares
I have been reading Steve Keen's newsletter recently, and in one of them he mentions Minsky software, which is an economic modelling software where you drag & drop icons, and you can obtain the equations. I find that pretty cool and was wondering if there was other software for econ modelling that would do pretty much the same thing ?

Do you mean economic modelling as theoretical models or econometric modelling as regression etc.?

For econometric modelling, SPSS and STATA both have drop-down menus that can do a lot of analyses including regression, ANOVA, t or chi-square tests, even time series stuff etc

Thanks ! I mean theoretical models ! Sorry for the confusion

Not quite sure what you mean by 'modelling software'; e.g. Microsoft Excel has a lot of built in econ tools, and you can input formulas for anything you could want, but I would hesitate to call it modelling software.
A 'drag & drop' software I heard about is Jamovi, which is built upon the R statistical language.

Oh I meant economic modelling like DSGE !
